# Finding public sharing link to other's Facebook album

Tags: facebook, links, sharing, album

If you own a Facebook photo album, it provides you with the public URL at the bottom that works even when not logged in.

Are any methods available to determine such public URL links to albums posted by others,  without learning them from the owners?

Sharing the link as visible to me (logged in) doesn't load elsewhere.

Comment: I really doubt it. The keys are unique to each and every album.